# How to validate controls in each column of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation

I would like to validate columns in an asp:Gridview but am unsure how to do so as all the tutorials I have found show a previous version on Microsoft Visual Studio (I am using 2010).

How do I validate each column of the Gridview?

Thanks

This is the code of my Gridview generated by visual studio.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="registrationNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fullName" HeaderText="fullName" 
            SortExpression="fullName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" 
            SortExpression="address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="work" HeaderText="work" 
            SortExpression="work" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="home" HeaderText="home" SortExpression="home" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile" HeaderText="mobile" 
            SortExpression="mobile" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="registrationNo" HeaderText="registrationNo" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="registrationNo" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" 
            ShowHeader="True" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update" HeaderText="Update" 
            ShowHeader="True" Text="Update" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
            ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#33CC33" />
    <RowStyle BorderStyle="Double" Font-Names="Monotype Corsiva" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you post what code you have so far please

Answer (score 0):

//native asp.net clientside validation (ATLAS Ajax)

Instead of using BoundFields you should use TemplateField. This will allow you to add Validation controls in the field i.e.

[Tutorial from 2007 which is still pertinent to this question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx)

//serverside validation

In order to validate the values on the server side you have a couple of options:

a) add a CustomValidator pointing to codebehind server validation method i.e. [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx)
b) on the gridviews RowUpdating method you could validate manually (this would also be for batch updates)

Comment: Yes this tutorial is using vs2008 BUT the UI differences are minor and you should be able to work around minor UI layout differences + you should be able to do it without the editor (it's only there as a speed improvement - mastering it in notepad first will give you the best knowledge)

Comment: That was exactly my question :(
NotePad ++ is good but not for designing web applications!
if u know how to do it in notepad, I would be happy to know it!

Comment: by using notepad i mean you know the code so well you don't need the code generation given by VS2010 (in otherwords you can code mostly from memory). I wouldn't recommend using notepad just get used to using 'view as source' and manually typing in the control code in there (not reliant on vs2010 drag and drop functionallity)

Comment: actually it is a homework, and i just want to do it now!
but for professional programing I agree to you, and I try not to use IDEs...
Thanks!

Comment: :) Okay so did you manage to get it working from the links I gave you?

Comment: Yes, I read it, but I have some problem in step1 it says:Open the UIValidation.aspx page. I cant find this class name in any place of my project.

Comment: Do you mean you downloaded the sample code and it is missing the UIValidation.aspx page? @Narges